# Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: macos, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

i am using macbook pro os x El Capitan version 10.11.6, i just started learning python and i installed python 3x on my computer then i tried to install jupyter. after running the command:

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

every thing worked fine but when i try to run the command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

i get the following error:

```
-bash: jupyter: command not found
```

i also tried: `python3 -m jupyter notebook`

```
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can any one help?

Comment: I thin you need to edit your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Please explain further @Sam Chats because i have tried to add the path of the jupyter to my $PATH and still not working. So i will greatly appreciate if further explanation is given because i am relatively new to unix environment thanks.

Comment: I fixed the issue by Navigating to /Applications/Python 3.6 in finder and double clicking on "Update Shell Profile.command"

Comment: Well then, add it as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to the `jupyter.exe` file and run jupyter notebook, does that work?

I had the same error in Windows 10.  What worked for me was putting `jupyter` in the environment variables path,

e.g.:

`C:\Anaconda\Scripts\.`

For Mac, +1 for the bash comment. Might consider adding the `jupyter` path to your .bash file